# .NET framework 3.5 not available

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am setting up a new 2008 SQL server on Windows 2008 R2 and it requires .NET framework 3.5. Unfortunately when I go to Features in the server manager, it only lists 3.0 and it is already installed.
Our WSUS has all required and security updates enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, download it from Microsoft... ? You don't see it in your WSUS because it's neither required nor a security update, I'll wildly guess.

Although, this is odd. [Wikipedia tells me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) that 3.5 is the default in 2008 R2. Are you sure you've got R2?

Comment: I don't think there is a Disk 2 for 2008 R2, you're thinking 2003 R2.  For 2008 R2 .Net 3.5 is there, you need to add the feature using the server manager.

Comment: I have just been doing 2003 R2 installs, you're entirely correct that 2008 R2 is a single DVD image. My bad.

Comment: But as Brian says, he's in Server Manager looking at Features, so I'm not sure what he's missing.

Comment: Yea, I think you're right, I think he's actually got 2008, not R2.

Comment: No, its definitely 2008 R2. I ended up doing what mfinni suggested and downloaded manually from Microsoft instead of enabling it locally on our WSUS